# Check if function is executed

Tags: python

First of all, sorry for the lack of precision from the title, I was not inspired. 
 
My goal is to check if a class method has been called after a certain timeout. 
So far, my code is the following:

```
class MyCallCallback(pj.CallCallback):
    def __init__(self, call=None):
        pj.CallCallback.__init__(self, call)

    # Notification when call state has changed
    def on_state(self):
       # Do stuff

        if self.call.info().state == pj.CallState.DISCONNECTED:
            # Do stuff

        elif self.call.info().state == pj.CallState.CONFIRMED:
            # Do stuff

    # Notification when call's media state has changed.
    def on_media_state(self):
        if self.call.info().media_state == pj.MediaState.ACTIVE:
            # Do stuff
        else:
            # Do stuff
```

And is called this way:

```
def make_call(uri):
    try:
        return acc.make_call(uri, cb=MyCallCallback)
    except pj.Error, e:
        print "Exception: " + str(e)
        return None
```

When I call the Callback, I would like to check if the event `on_state` from `MyCallBack` is triggered after a timeout. 
I tried stuff like that:

```
timeout = time.time() + 1
 while time.time() > timeout:
     if [on_state is no triggered]
        sys.exit(-1)
```

But can't find a way to do it properly.

Would you have any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I can't use a flag system like this one:

```
class MyCallCallback(pj.CallCallback):
    on = 0
    timeout = time.time() + 5
    while time.time() < timeout:
        print "Waiting ..."
        pass

    if on != 1:
        print "Fail"
        sys.exit(-1)

    def __init__(self, call=None):
        pj.CallCallback.__init__(self, call)
        self.on = 0

    # Notification when call state has changed
    def on_state(self):
        print "ON_STATE"
        self.on = 1
```

Since it will be synchronous.

Comment: `on_state` could flip a boolean object-scoped variable when it executes. I don't know if this is the *right* solution, but it's a solution. `self.on = 0`, `on_state` : `self.on = 1`.

Comment: What API are you using? Most will take a timeout parameter as well as a callback parameter.

Comment: I am using PJSIP: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Accounts

Comment: @spectre-d: See my edit :)